# Show that some 5 consecutive chairs must be occupied.

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

A group of 25 people are seated in a row of 30 chairs. Show that some 5 consecutive chairs must be occupied.

Comment: Related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121561/pigeonhole-principle-question It may help.

Comment: ty, I got it! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there are 25 people and 30 chairs, there are 5 empty seats. Divide the row of 30 chairs into 6 groups of 5 consecutive seats. Since there are 6 groups and 5 empty chairs, at least one of the 6 groups has no empty seats. So in that group with no empty seats, all five consecutive seats are full.

Answer (score 0):

Place single empty chairs so there's 4 full chairs between them.  Obviously they can't be pushed further apart, as a group of 5 full chairs would then exist.  How much do you have stuck on the end after you've placed them all?